# SwiftUI Layout image with borders

Tags: swiftui

(My apologies in advance if this has been answered multiple times)

I want a simple stack layout of an image between top and bottom views. Here is a trivial version:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        border
        simpleMiddle
        border
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}

var border: some View {
    return ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.green)
            .frame(minHeight: borderHeight, maxHeight: borderHeight)
    }
}

var simpleMiddle: some View {
    return ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.purple)
    }
}
```

It creates what I expect:

[image: Simple layout with borders]

The problem arises when I change out the middle to include an image, replacing `simpleMiddle` with this:

```
var imageMiddle: some View {
    return ZStack {
        Image("cat")
            .scaledToFill() // or Fit, or nothing
    }
}
```

The image takes up all the space, and I lose the borders. What I want are the two borders to remain visible, and the image to have less priority, i.e. "fit behind" the borders. What is the SwiftUI way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an image into overlay, like

```
var imageMiddle: some View {
    return ZStack {
        Color.clear.overlay(   // << here !!
          Image("cat")
            .scaledToFill()
        )
        .clipped()   // << here !!
    }
}
```